# How come my image is not being drawn to the panel after I had made the image object using imageIcon().getImage()?

Tags: java, image

```
package notes.shape;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    final int WIDTH=500;
    final int HEIGHT=500;
    Image bird;
    Timer timer;
    int x=0, y=0, xVel=7, yVel=5;

    MyPanel(){
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); //makes panel 500x500
        this.setBackground(Color.decode("#909599"));
        bird=new ImageIcon("dvd.png").getImage(); //creates an image from dvd.png
        System.out.println(bird.getHeight(null)); //tells the height and width of the image
        System.out.println(bird.getWidth(null));
        timer=new Timer(10, this); //initiates the timer
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
      super.paint(g); //makes the background a light gray
      Graphics2D g2D=(Graphics2D) g; //cast g to Graphics2D
      g2D.drawImage(bird, x, y, null); //draws the image on the panel
    
      g2D.setColor(Color.decode("#ed1532")); //draws a red rectangle
      g2D.fillRect(y, x, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(x>=WIDTH-bird.getWidth(null)||x<0) //switches the direction where the drawing is going on the x-axis
            xVel*=-1;
        x+=xVel;

        if(y>=HEIGHT-bird.getHeight(null)||y<0) //switches the direction on the y-axis 
            yVel*=-1;
        y+=yVel;
        repaint(); //redraws at the new position
    }
}
```

The purpose of this code is to draw a dvd image on a panel where it bounces off the walls; however, I having trouble drawing the image. I have a red square as a placeholder for right now, which is being drawn fine, but the problem with my image is that it is not being created in bird=new ImageIcon("dvd.png").getImage(); because it keeps showing the width and height as -1. Is there a reason why it's not being created such as using ImageIcon?

Comment: Use `ImageIO` to read the image. You will get an Exception if the image can't be read.

Comment: Better to load your files/images as resources:
https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans
https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse
Also, you should be overriding `paintComponent`